# Android sqlite where, like and orderby together

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

I am trying to get all row from  SQLite database that is in following pattern which starts with **Group** and ends with **(General)**.:

```
Group n (General)
Group n+1 (General)
Group n+1+... (General)
```

Since, I am using SQL like for the first time, at present I tried it with raw query which looks like below. This is throwing an SQLException because my query isn't correct.

```
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_LOCATION
            + " FROM " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + KEY_LOCATION
            + " ASC" + " WHERE " + KEY_LOCATION + " LIKE '"
            + "%Group%%%%General%" + "'", null);
```

Here is a stacktrace from above execution:

```
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT suggest_text_1 FROM FTSlocation ORDER BY suggest_text_1 ASC WHERE suggest_text_1 LIKE '%Group%%%%General%'
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-08 09:38:49.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4082):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
```

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve it or may be hint on how do I proceed?

Comment: The wild card `%` means one or more characters, so you don't need to use more than one `%` in a row: `%Group%General%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ORDER BY` clause after the `WHERE`.

That should make it